# 'Inappbrowser plugin already exists' when building phonegap app

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

I understand that this is related to duplicate files in the project but I just can't find the files and I have deleted barely everything that could be related to this problem. I deleted inside 'plugins' folder and don't understand if I should be deleting anything else because I don't find anything more. Any idea? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Are you not just removing the plugin from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Under plugins folder, you will find .json files specific to the platforms. For android, you may have to edit android.json file inside plugins folder and remove the plugin reference in the file. Similarly for iOS, you may have to look for ios.json